# How to Wrap a Variadic Template Function?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

Let's say, I have something like

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Arg>
void helper(Arg&& arg) {
    // do something with the type and value
}

void vt(){}

template <class Arg, class... Args>
void vt(Arg&& arg, Args&&... rest) {
    helper(arg);
    vt(rest...);
}

int main() {
    vt(1, 1.1, "abc");
}
```

Now, my question is that how I can wrap a variadic template function like `vt()` in a cpp file.  Basically, I would like to hide the implementation from the clients in my library.

I thought about using `va_list` but it is slow and more importantly, in order to iterate through the list, I need to know the type in advance, which is impossible as I don't know what the callers might pass in (besides the variable arguments have to be of primitive C types).

If the solution requires GCC specific stuffs, I am okay with it too.

If the solution has to drop variadic template, it is okay as long as the solution can iterate variable arguments, get the type of each argument (`helper()` needs the info), and get the value of each argument.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out c++ modules, I'm not sure if that actually hides the source or not )it may even be an implementation detail). In general c++ compilers require that template source be visible in each translation unit that uses the template.

Comment: What is your purpose for hiding the implementation? Prevent "secrets" from being known, or prevent user of your library accidentally misusing an implementation detail? IOW, Machiavelli or Murphy?

Comment: I think, use `va_list` and I think you can make an inline wrapper function that calls the function with type and values

Comment: @StoryTeller haha, good reminder.  Tho, just like most commercial software, protecting the IP (secret) is necessary sometimes :)

Comment: @SoronelHaetir interesting new feature.  never aware until you mentioned.  tho, it won't come until C++20, which my GCC (7.2) compiler hasn't supported it yet.  I will keep it on my list.  Will check again later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, but it involves the `typeinfo`, which maybe questionable for performance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdarg>
using namespace std;

// This is the function you could puts its implementation in a separate file
// Use only its prototype in the header
void funcWithValist(int count, ...) {
    va_list a;
    va_start(a, count);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        // Here is an example to extract the type info (you can use anything
        // instead of name() )
        cout << va_arg(a, std::type_info *)->name() << "\n";
    }
}

// The C++ wrapper function, this is to be put in the header file
template<typename... T>
void funcWithArgs(const T&... t) {
    funcWithValist(sizeof...(t), (&typeid(t))..., t...);
    // Expanded into: the number of args, &typeid(arg1), &typeid(arg2), ...
    //                arg1, arg2, ... 
}

int main() {
    // Example of the call
    funcWithArgs(4, std::string("Aaa"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of `va_arg()` with `std::type_info`; I always thought I would need to provide the real type and so I thought iterating through `va_list` weren't possible with "unknown" types.  I think I can expand your solution a bit by storing compile time type into a `uint8_t enum` and then using a `switch` in `funcWithValist()` to accelerate.

Comment: You also could use a wrapper class that is somewhat like `boost::any` and pass pointers to them as va_args, and make this wrapper class has `enum` and a pointer to the `value`, and also you could make a virtual `copy` function

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that templates must be in header for a good reason. In other words it is not that some arcane language rule decided so.

Reason for this is that template functions are **not** functions. They are **templates** that enable you to produce functions. And for that user code needs to be able to see the entire template definition.

Note that if you do not require your template to work with every possible type and any possible arity you can do something ugly like this, but I recommend against it.

```
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<vector>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<variant>
    using my_v=std::variant<std::monostate, int, double, const char*>;
    void func(const my_v& a1= std::monostate{}, const my_v& a2 = std::monostate{},
              const my_v& a3 = std::monostate{} );
    struct visitor{
        void operator()(const my_v& v) const{
            if (std::holds_alternative<int>(v)){
                std::cout << "got int: " << std::get<int>(v) << std::endl;
            }
            if (std::holds_alternative<const char*>(v)){
                std::cout << "got string: " << std::get<const char*>(v) << std::endl;
            }
            if (std::holds_alternative<double>(v)){
                std::cout << "got double: " << std::get<double>(v) << std::endl;
            }
            if (std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>(v)){
                // empty function argument
            }

        }
    };

    void func(const my_v& a1, const my_v& a2, const my_v& a3){
        std::visit(visitor{}, a1); 
        std::visit(visitor{}, a2); 
        std::visit(visitor{}, a3); 
    }

    int main()
    {
        func(double{42}, "hello");
    }
```